# EF 4.4 Doesn't detect changes done by AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using a repository patter for my webApi, and trying to make Update work.
What this does is receives a "new" entity from the mvc webapi controller, and tries to update the existing object

```
public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {

            var oldEntry = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);

            oldEntry = Mapper.Map(entity, oldEntry);

            Console.WriteLine(oldEntry.ToString());

            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Save changes does nothing.

If I explicitly specify

```
oldEntry.SomeTextProperty = "TestText";
```

and then call

```
 _context.SaveChanges();
```

all is good. 
How to fix this ? or work around this ?
Maybe there is a way to tell AutoMapper to invoke property setters ?

Comment: EF 5, when used with .Net 4.5 has an extension for this Set<T>.AddOrUpdate.. but unfortunately I'm working on .Net 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell EF that you modified your entity before saving changes.
This should work in framework 4.5

```
_context.Set<TEntity>().AddOrUpdate(new[] {oldEntry});
```

Or maybe this in framework 4:

```
_context.Entry(oldEntry).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: Yes, it would it it was there. No such method on on the Set<T> :(

Comment: Ok, indeed sorry, this was old way of doing it. I updated my answer to be EF 5 compliant... but this may not work for you as you are in .Net 4...

Comment: Yep, that if on EF 5. and .Net 4.5. Which I cannot use. Azure has no support for it yet. That's why I've specified ef 4.4 in the description.

Comment: changing the state = State.Modified, produces the following ERR : Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Found the way to use AddOrUpdate for EF 4.4. Needed to import this Lib System.Data.Entity.Migrations; has an extension method : AddOrUpdate<TEntity>(this IDbSet<TEntity> set, params [ParamArray] TEntity[] entities) 
in class IDbSetExtensions

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess:

AutoMapper uses reflexion to update values, and it does a good job at it.

However it doesn't call whatever is in the setter of the property, so the context is unaware of changes done by AutoMapper, and SaveChanges() doesn't do anything.

You could try to use EmitMapper, which doesn't use reflexion.